# `Invalid format for configuration file` when trying to connect to a local orientdb database

Tags: orientdb

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and have all the orientdb relevant files in `/opt/orientdb`.
So, first I open a console and run `sudo bash /opt/orientdb/bin/server.sh`, which works fine.
Then i open a separate console and try to `sudo bash /opt/orientdb/bin/console.sh`, which works fine as well.
And then from the console I try to `connect plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/VehicleHistoryGraph user password` and get an error:

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'VehicleHistoryGraph'

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Invalid format for configuration file /opt/orientdb/bin/../databases/VehicleHistoryGraph/database.ocf for storageVehicleHistoryGraph
```

Is there a way for me to fix the configuration file?

ETA: downloading and unzipping a public database over the version that I had didn't fix the issue.

ETA: `GratefulDeadConcerts` and `Tolkien-Arda` work just fine.

Comment: Hi, What version are you using? I tried with version 2.2.32 and it worked.

Comment: I started with 3.0.2 and then installed and tried 3.0.4